# How many words does a Period entail?

Tags: sentence, periods, sentence-ends

What is the minimum number of words that need to be observed for the last word to be punctuated with a period?

For instance, I have a Topic/Label with 4 words that reads like a sentence ("Dialog Augmented Reunion Centre").

In this label/topic which is actually presented in a "Powerpoint" Slide, I believe that the words should be presented as follows:
"Dialog Augmented Reunion Centre." -Please note the Period after "Centre".

How further or otherwise is this ideology from what is expounded as gramatically correct?

Comment: Periods end sentences not strings of words. The minimum number of words for a sentence is one.  A label is not a sentence.  The only way I can agree that your 4 words are a sentence is if “Reunion Centre” is the name of a centre somewhere and you are saying that there was some dialog and that dialog somehow served to augment the centre.  And in that case *augmented* should not be capitalized.

Comment: "Dialog Augmented Reunion Centre" is not a sentence and does not use a period. Period.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think there's any formal rule for this; it's a matter of style. Labels aren't really sentences, and so they don't need to be punctuated as such. In general, Powerpoint topic headers aren't punctuated. I think your slide will look more natural without a period, but it wouldn't be an error, per se, to include one.

Edit to add: A phrase as short as one word can be a full sentence, while a phrase of an infinite number of words could be not a sentence. It really doesn't have anything to do with length.

Comment: "... it wouldn't be an error, per se, to include one." Error, per what, please?

Comment: Sorry, it's just an expression that means "it wouldn't be an error, exactly, to include one." Just ignore the "per se" and you'll get the same meaning.

Comment: I meant to ask "error, according to what?" I do know what's *per se*.

Answer (score 0):

You can format according to whatever style you like.

> "It's too cute. I. Just. Can't."

The above is not, technically, four "proper" sentences, and could be described as one sentence and three "sentence fragments." (However, the single word "Yes," as an answer to a question, is a meaningful single-word sentence—mostly because the "rest" of the sentence is implied, even if not stated.) But in informal text like this, periods can be used to express large pauses and emphasis.

In addition to indicating a large pause, a period, along with a capital first letter, is simply a visual cue that signals the endpoint of a sentence.

Headings and titles, generally, are not sentences, and so do not have periods at the end. Mainly because there aren't "multiple things" that need to be separated. Topics and labels, such as yours, are seldom punctuated with a terminal period. Just as they seldom contain any punctuation marks aside from, sometimes, a colon.